# Using __FILE__ in Bazel leads to undeterministic builds

Tags: c++, bazel, build-system

In my code I use a fair amount of `__FILE__` defines, and unfortunately they are absolute (and not relative to a given path). I am using Perforce, and therefore different branches are not checked out on the same path, so `__FILE__` is different on every translation unit (of course).

That means 20 branches with the same content do not match the same object file cache since they have technically a different content.

Any idea how I can address this issue?

Comment: Is a hack like `__SHORT_FILE__` an option for you? https://blog.galowicz.de/2016/02/20/short_file_macro/

Comment: Unfortunately it still relies on `__FILE__` and does the `constexpr` I already tried

Comment: Well, but you're talking about the object file cache - the computed value of `__SHORT_FILE__` should be statically compiled into the binary and the actual value of `__FILE__` should not be referenced in the final object file, I think.